# Read text file and print in the same format

Tags: php, file, text

i want to read a text file on a php page and print (echo) the content in the same form (with the paragraphs). So i tried two implementations

**Code 1**

```
$textfile = "teste.txt"; // Declares the name and location of the .txt file
$content="";
$fileLocation = "$textfile";
$fh = fopen($fileLocation, 'w   ');
if (is_readable($textfile)) {
$content .= fread($fh, 8192);
echo $content;
} else {
    echo 'The file is not readable.';
}
fclose($fh);

?>
```

Using this code nothing apper on the screen. and i had another problem. If i used *filesize ($textfile)* on the *fread* i had this error *Length parameter must be greater than 0*.So i guess this is the problem. but the text file has content

**Code 2**

```
<?php 
$homepage = file_get_contents('teste.txt');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

This code works. but the format is not what i want.
the echo prints this

> 25 ºC 26 ºC 27 ºC 26 ºC 26 ºC
>   I want that appear one value on each line like i have on the text file.

What can i do to acomplish that
Thanks for the help

Comment: to easy: [nl2br()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php), browsers expect html

Comment: @Dagon, it worked like a charm! I research so mutch for this and i dont found the answare. maybe i asked the work questions and used the wrong terms.
Thank you so mutch for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note sure if this is answerd, but try this

```
<?php
    $file = "LOCATION/NAME.txt";
    $text = file_get_contents($file);
    $text = nl2br($text);



    echo $text; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be as simple as wrapping the output inside the PRE tag:

```
<?php 
$homepage = file_get_contents('teste.txt');
echo '<PRE>' . $homepage . '</PRE>';
?>
```

This will work better than nl2br() if you also need to keep the exact number of spaces due to needing a fixed-width font.  HTML normally turns two or three spaces in a row into just one.  But inside a PRE tag if you have 3 spaces, all 3 will be displayed.

Comment: Please state the reason downvoter. This works perfect, and has added benefits over the other suggestion.